# How to pass the output from previous step to the next one in Azure Data Factory V2?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have built a sequence of activities in Data Factory as shown in the image below.

[image]

I am wondering how I can capture and pass the SQL Server output (including error messages) from `Step 1` in `Step 2`. As shown in the screenshot, I am currently using `@activity('PR_TEST_RAISE_ERROR').output` in the hope that it captures the error message like `ERROR: test error message`, but when I checked the log table, the message that we got from using `@activity('PR_TEST_RAISE_ERROR').output` is like this:

[image]

In case anyone wants to replicate what I'm facing, the code for stored procedure in `Step 1` is as follows:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PR_TEST_RAISE_ERROR]
AS
RAISERROR ('ERROR: test error message',16,1);

GO
```

For `Step 2` when Step 1 is successful, I have it run a stored procedure with the parameters like this:

```
exec [dbo].[PR_TEST_LOG_ERROR_CATCHING] '[pr_test_sql_error_catching]', 'success'
```

For `Step 2` when Step 1 has failed, I have it run the same stored procedure as follows:

```
exec [dbo].[PR_TEST_LOG_ERROR_CATCHING] '[pr_test_sql_error_catching]', 'failure'
```

where the `[dbo].[PR_TEST_LOG_ERROR_CATCHING]` is coded like this:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PR_TEST_LOG_ERROR_CATCHING]
                            (
                                @log_table_name AS NVARCHAR(100),
                                @message AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
                            )
AS
DECLARE @cur_date DATETIME = getdate();
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @query = (
            'INSERT INTO [dbo].' + @log_table_name 
            + '(
                [Message],
                [Logged_On]
            )
            VALUES ('''
            + @message + ''','
            + '''' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @cur_date) + ''''
            + ');'
        );

    EXEC (@query)
GO
```

and the log table (`@log_table_name`) `[pr_test_sql_error_catching]` is created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    Message nvarchar(max),
    Logged_On datetime
);
```

If anyone is curious about the source code for the whole Data Factory activity sequence, it's like this:

```
{
    "name": "pr_test_sql_error_catching",
    "properties": {
        "description": "Example pipeline showing how we can catch SQL errors",
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "PR_TEST_RAISE_ERROR",
                "description": "[dbo].[PR_TEST_RAISE_ERROR]",
                "type": "SqlServerStoredProcedure",
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "typeProperties": {
                    "storedProcedureName": "[dbo].[PR_TEST_RAISE_ERROR]"
                },
                "linkedServiceName": {
                    "referenceName": "pr_us_programmatic_sql_db",
                    "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "PR_TEST_LOG_ERROR_CATCHING_When_successful",
                "description": "[dbo].[PR_TEST_LOG_ERROR_CATCHING]",
                "type": "SqlServerStoredProcedure",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "PR_TEST_RAISE_ERROR",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "typeProperties": {
                    "storedProcedureName": "[dbo].[PR_TEST_LOG_ERROR_CATCHING]",
                    "storedProcedureParameters": {
                        "log_table_name": {
                            "value": "[pr_test_sql_error_catching]",
                            "type": "String"
                        },
                        "message": {
                            "value": "success",
                            "type": "String"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "linkedServiceName": {
                    "referenceName": "pr_sql_db",
                    "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "PR_TEST_LOG_ERROR_CATCHING_When_Errored",
                "type": "SqlServerStoredProcedure",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "PR_TEST_RAISE_ERROR",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Failed"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "typeProperties": {
                    "storedProcedureName": "[dbo].[PR_TEST_LOG_ERROR_CATCHING]",
                    "storedProcedureParameters": {
                        "log_table_name": {
                            "value": "[pr_test_sql_error_catching]",
                            "type": "String"
                        },
                        "message": {
                            "value": {
                                "value": "@activity('PR_TEST_RAISE_ERROR').output",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            },
                            "type": "String"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "linkedServiceName": {
                    "referenceName": "pr_sql_db",
                    "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines"
}
```

Thank you in advance for your answers/suggestions as to how I can pass error message (or any kind of output) from previous step to next in Azure Data Factory!